# Oracle BPM 11g Organization Unit

Tags: java, oracle11g, business-process-management

I've been searching for a way to retrieve the Organization Units contained in Oracle BPM 11g in order to get the defined hierarchy.

I've heard of the fuego.fdi package but JDeveloper doesn't look like recognizing it. Checked the IdentityService, but It looks like it can only get users from weblogic and not the hiearchy defined by the organization units.

can anyone point me to the right direction, an example would be great, but just the right API classes would be fine.

Thanks

Comment: i could be wrong but thought that fuego was 10.3

Comment: That's what I think, so I've discarted fuego for now

Answer (score 0):

There is no fuego FDI concept in 11g as similar like 10gr3. 11g supports configuring any of organizational Identity structures such as LDAP or Active Directory through weblogic authentication providers . Please refer this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13707/atn.htm#SECMG169)